# Incorrect average turnaround time calculated for FCFS schedule?

Tags: algorithms, operating-systems, scheduling, process-scheduling

I am trying to solve the following problem:

If all of the jobs listed below are scheduled FCFS (First Come, First Serve) with no switching overhead, the average turnaround time is going to be:

```
Arrival Duration
0       10
1       9
2       8
3       7
4       6
```

My calculation is: (10 + (10 + 9) + (10 + 9 + 8) + (10 + 9 + 8 + 7) + (10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6))/5 = **26**

However, that is apparentally incorrect. I am confused, as I believe that I am using the average turnaround formula correctly?

Comment: The second job arrives at time 1 and is handled by time 19. This is a turnaround time of 18, not 19. Same for subsequent jobs.

Comment: Try not using a formula. Instead, make sure that you understand what *turnaround time* and *average turnaround time* mean.